# Know my novell server version and adding a user

Tags: user-management, novell

how do i know the version of novell on my server when it has already been installed?

How do i add a user to the novell user? is there a graphical user interface to manage novell services?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find out the server version by typing VERSION at the server console. You can switch between screens of the server by pressing Alt-Esc, or switch to a particular screen by pressing Ctrl-Esc and selecting its number.

The way you add users depends on the version of the server. Provided it is a relatively recent one, switch to the graphics screen or type STARTX at the server console, and run ConsoleOne from the main menu

Answer (score 2):

If you are running Novell Netware, then as Dmityugov suggests, VERSION at the console.

If you are running OES on Linux, then ssh to the server (or login at the Linux console, GUI or console only) and execute `oes-SPident` to see what version of OES you are running and regular `SPident` to see what version of SLES you are running.

As for a UI, ConsoleOne is the Java based user administrative tool.  You can still download it from Novell.  On Windows it requires an NCP connection which is provided by Client32.  On Linux it uses JClient to make the NCP connection.  So if you can install it on Linux it is much simpler.

The newer approach is iManager, a web based management tool.  On Netware, try `java -show` and look for a org.catalina.something reference, though this is more complex, as it might not be a tomcat with iManager installed instance, and then try http://serverIP/nps.  If it is not running on standard port 80/443 then it is likely on 8080/8443.  Figuring that out requires reading config files, which is not terrible but beyond the scope of this response I would think.